# Query for OR condition, when number of values are dynamic

Tags: linq

How to add OR condition dynamically in query. Code Using EF5.0, LINQ , MVC4.0 and repository pattern.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
      var model = new AssignedSearchFields();   //ViewModel
      List<LClient.Model.Attribute> allFields =                      Common.GetAssignedSearchFields(User.Identity.Name, userID, "EntityType Name 1");     
      model.SearchFields = allFields;  // List allFields having dynamic number of items.
      model.Entities = entityRepository.GetMany(e => e.EntityTypeID == 1 && e.InstanceID <= 10 && (e.AttributeID == 1 || e.AttributeID == 2 || e.AttributeID == 3 || e.AttributeID == 4)); // Here I want to use AttributeID dynamically without OR conditions.
      return View(model);    
}
```

Comment: Use `PredicateBuilder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you need `PredicateBuilder` in this case

`Contains` should be enough.

```
var dynamicIds = new[]{1, 2, 3, 4};

//or something like that, if you want values coming from 'GetAssignedSearchFields'
var dynamicIds = Common.GetAssignedSearchFields(User.Identity.Name, userID, "EntityType Name 1")
                   .Select(m => m.Id);
//xxx
      model.Entities = entityRepository.GetMany(e => 
                          e.EntityTypeID == 1 && 
                          e.InstanceID <= 10 
                          && (dynamicIds.Contains(e.AttributeID));
```